# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkVideoPlayer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pip

How to get the missing 'tkVideoPlayer'?

I got this error after running my file vid_play.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\vid_play.py", line 2, in <module>
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkVideoPlayer'`
```

My file vid_play.py reads:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo

root = tk.Tk()

videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=root, scaled=True, pre_load=False)
videoplayer.load(r"C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\samplevideo.mp4")
videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

videoplayer.play() # play the video

root.mainloop()
```

I ran `pip list` and got:

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ----------
    tk                        0.1.0
    tkinterdnd2               0.3.0
    tkintervideo              0.0.2
    tkVideo                   0.1
```

This issue still exists. I expected a complete installation.

Comment: Try running `pip install tkvideoplayer` [source](https://pypi.org/project/tkvideoplayer/)

Comment: First you need to do this py -m pip install --no-deps tkvideoplayer --upgrade. Then try this  https://github.com/PaulleDemon/tkVideoPlayer/blob/master/examples/sample_player.py

Comment: In your script, remove `pre_load`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in error, you don't have tkvideoplayer module.tkvideoplayer is a different module. You need to download tkvideoplayer module.

```
$ pip install tkvideoplayer
```

Comment: Also just to note: the `tk` pip package isn't `tkinter`. `tkinter` is part of the standard library that comes preinstalled with python.

Comment: Thanks for correcting and fixing misunderstanding

Comment: I ran 'pip install tkvideoplayer' and got an incomplete package. The response ended:

 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Comment: @CANJMP Note that latest version 2.5 of `tkvideoplayer` has dependency on `av==9.1.1` but version 9.1.1 of `av` does not have binary release for Python 3.11+.  So if your Python version is 3.11+, you need to install the dependent modules (`av` and `pillow`) first and then run `pip install --no-deps tkvideoplayer`.  Or just run `pip install --only-binary :all: tkvideoplayer`.

Comment: Sorry I decide to abandon Python. It was uninstalled including the Path. This is do to the unpredictability of the install and dependencies.  It is too unstable. Thanks to all for your assistance.